# receiving gps signal from sensor - matlab

Tags: matlab, gps, signals, sensors

is it possible to receive GPS signal (in Matlab) from sensor that will show me position changes of an object? I've never try do it before and I'm total noob in that kind of problem, so if anyone could give any advices...

Comment: does sensor provide a serial or ethernet connection?

Comment: oh, not sure, but serial i guess

Comment: if it provides serial connection , you could use it to read its data from  matlab usin  "serial" function, read matlab documentation for more info